# Blender Development question, thumbnails file icon selection?

Tags: file-browser

I have an issue of file management with so many textures and was wondering if blender has a solution or if it will be developed?

I have many files with textures, that include 1 texture with many images like albedo, roughness, normal etc.

These files only show a file because of multiple images inside.

Is there a way of assigning one of the file images to the file icon?

Otherwise I have to read each name to guess what texture I want.

If not, it may be beneficial to develop a file icon with a border and an image inside with file image selection option.

Though I hope someone can point me in the right direction of a solution (please).

A material Library add-on that comes with blender, does not work with thumbnails, or show a tutorial anywhere I have seen to add a library to it.

The "Chocofur" materials library works but it seems very long winded changing every file name and texture, too complicated, takes ages. Also, who says it will be supported for later versions.

Is their not a plan to just have the file icon have a border, with the first image inside the file as the thumbnail inside the border, no need for add-ons and libraries then is there? As the first file can be made to be the albedo by name changes that are simple.

Or if someone knows a really decent materials manager, great, but I haven't seen one that is simple. No version problems either.

Comment: Try if [Texture Library Manager](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-texture-library-manager/629462) addon helps you. I hope that's what you're aiming for...

Comment: This helps a little for some materials for free, but the add_on does not show files, and I have not found a tutorial to add my own library/in what order etc.